# dynamic in C#, seting property value

Tags: c#

I nead to set a property for an object

```
Personi p = new Personi();//this class has a property Datelindja(DateTime)
p.Emri = "Florim";
p.Mbiemri = "Maxhuni";
SetValue(p, "Datelindja", DateTime.Now); //I nead these method. using dynamic keyword
Console.WriteLine(p.Ditelindja);
```

How do i implement this method that will set the value base on these parameters.

method signature

```
SetValue(dynamic orgObj, string property, dynamic value)
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you would need `dynamic` here.
`SetValue` will need to use reflection:

```
void SetValue<TInstance, TValue>(TInstance orgObj, string property, TValue value)
{
    orgObj.GetType().GetProperty(property).SetValue(orgObj, value, null);
}
```

You could also write this method without generics, because they don't add any benefit in this case:

```
void SetValue(object orgObj, string property, object value)
{
    orgObj.GetType().GetProperty(property).SetValue(orgObj, value, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The opensource project [Dyamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey) has a method [Dynamic.InvokeSet](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#dynamic-invokesetobject-target-string_or_invokemembername-name-object-value) that uses DLR plumbing to accomplish that. While in your example you can indeed use reflection since the object itself isn't an IDynamicMetaObjectProvider, but by using Dynamic (dlr)  not only will it be more flexible but it will average 3x faster than reflection.

```
Dynamic.InvokeSet(p,"Datelindja", DateTime.Now)
```